# Change Fragment Activity with button in the same activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to change fragment activity by using button in the same fragment activity i want to repace. But when i press the button before the fragmenet change the apps crash because activity has been destroyed before the second fragment show up. How i solve this?

```
            eMoney.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                accountActivity.showEMoney();
            }
        });

`   
public void showEMoney(){
        Fragment fragment = new EMoney();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.translate_right, R.anim.translate_left).replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }`

    public class EMoney extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_emoney, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your log..

Comment: Add more detatils

Comment: The Log says:
activity has been destroyed

Comment: please your grammar is lacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `showEMoney()` method by itself, not on `accountActivity`. You need to change `accountActivity.showEMoney();` to `showEMoney();` inside `onClick()`.